# How can i get list of all files with their paths in c

Tags: c, path, directory

I have read many ways to get list of all files in a directory (e.g. [scan a directory to find files in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149569/scan-a-directory-to-find-files-in-c)), but I also want to get their full paths (eg `C:\example\file.mp3`).

How is it possible?

Comment: Maybe `strcat` helps. But you should probably provide some code you are working on...

Comment: Does it have to be cross platform?

Comment: the code is linked but i want complete file paths

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use [`fts(3)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=fts&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html) there's the `fts_path` slot that contains the paths to the files relative to what you put in `fts_open()`.

So I imagine you'd open your directories like this:

```
char *dirs[] = {"C:\example", NULL}
fts_open(dirs, 0, NULL);
```

and then you get full paths in the `fts_path` member of the `FTSENT` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use dirent.h, it will enable you to populate something like a linked list with the full path of everything in that directory

Comment: its also cross platform, if thats needed/helps :)

Comment: __Is__ there a cross platform way for doing it?