# C get all files with certain extension

Tags: c, file

How to find all extensions in a directory with a ".ngl" extension?

Comment: What OS? Or do you need a cross-platform solution?

Comment: Look into opendir readdir and glob

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the list of file name with the same extension in a folder with one system call, you can try to use `scandir` instead of using `opendir` and `readdir`.  The only thing to remember is that you need to free the memory allocate by `scandir`.

```
   /* print files in current directory with specific file extension */
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <dirent.h>

   /* when return 1, scandir will put this dirent to the list */
   static int parse_ext(const struct dirent *dir)
   {
     if(!dir)
       return 0;

     if(dir->d_type == DT_REG) { /* only deal with regular file */
         const char *ext = strrchr(dir->d_name,'.');
         if((!ext) || (ext == dir->d_name))
           return 0;
         else {
           if(strcmp(ext, ".ngl") == 0)
             return 1;
         }
     }

     return 0;
   }

   int main(void)
   {
       struct dirent **namelist;
       int n;

       n = scandir(".", &namelist, parse_ext, alphasort);
       if (n < 0) {
           perror("scandir");
           return 1;
       }
       else {
           while (n--) {
               printf("%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);
               free(namelist[n]);
           }
           free(namelist);
       }

       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Why is having to `free()` memory a downside? That's what has to be done all the day...

Comment: What I am trying to say is that sometimes a programmer forgets to free the memory or unaware he/she should free the memory since it is allocated by `scandir` not the programmer himself/herself.

Comment: That is right, but holds for all kinds of memory allocations. Maybe the wording could be "The only thing to consider" or "to remember"...

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have standardised directory management, that's POSIX (or Windows if you're so inclined).
In POSIX, you can do something like:

1. Take the `char *` that contains the path to the directory
2. use `opendir()` on it, you get a `DIR *`
3. using `readdir()` on the `DIR *` repeatedly gives you the entries `struct dirent*` in the directory
4. the `stuct dirent*` contains the name of the file, including the extension (.ngl). It also contains info on whether the entry is a regular file or something else (a symlink, subdirectory, whatever)