# how to list all the .txt files in the current directory?

Tags: c, file, posix

I do know how to read all the files from the current directory by opening directory `"./"` and then using `readdir`. But, how do I list only `.txt` files or any other specific extension?

```
  DIR *p;
  struct dirent *pp;     
  p = opendir ("./");

  if (p != NULL)
  {
    while ((pp = readdir (p))!=NULL)
      puts (pp->d_name);

    (void) closedir (pp);
  }
```

Comment: Loop through the files as you currently do and process only those whose name finishes with the specific extension you chose ?

Comment: Use a `for` loop in conjunction with `sscanf`.  You could do something like count the number of '.' characters in the file name, then if everything after the last one read "txt", print the whole file name.

Comment: i think you are looking for http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob

Comment: ***[Look Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8149569/645128)***

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list files in a directory in a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204666/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-in-a-c-program)

Comment: @LPs: not of that particular question, the OP already got that far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the filename before you print it.

```
  DIR *p;
  struct dirent *pp;     
  p = opendir ("./");

  if (p != NULL)
  {
    while ((pp = readdir (p))!=NULL) {
      int length = strlen(pp->d_name);
      if (strncmp(pp->d_name + length - 4, ".txt", 4) == 0) {
          puts (pp->d_name);
      }
    }

    (void) closedir (p);
  }
```

Incidentally you were also calling `closedir()` on your `dirent` (pp) rather than your `DIR *` (p).

Comment: Isn't it more advisable to use a case indifferent compare? Or is that too OS dependent? (On Windows, `".txt" == ".TXT"` but my own Mac has two modes for this -- and I can never recall which one is for what.)

Comment: @Jongware Indeed it is.