# Scanning every file in a folder in c

Tags: c, file

I'm writing a program where I need to print all the files in a given folder and store the content of the files in order to compare it to another string. 
What I have now is:

```
while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if (!strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(ent->d_name, ".."))
            {
                // do nothing (straight logic)
            }
            else {

                file_name = ent->d_name;
                printf("%s\n", file_name);
                file_name = ent->d_name;
            printf("%s\n", file_name);
            char *fd = file_name;
            struct stat *buf;
            buf = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
            stat(fd, buf);
            int size = buf->st_size;
            printf("%d", size);
            }
        }
```

edit:
my problem now is that it prints the size as negative

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149569/scan-a-directory-to-find-files-in-c . Take a look at this post, it might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scan a directory to find files in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149569/scan-a-directory-to-find-files-in-c)

Comment: not exactly. specifically, I have a folder wich contains 2 png. I need to open each in binary mod and compare every one of them to another string I already have

Answer (score 0):

1. use `strstr()` to see if the filename ends with .png
2. for files that don't match, skip to the next file
3. for files that match, use `stat()` to get the file size
4. use `malloc()` to allocate a buffer of sufficient size to read in the file
5. use `fopen()` and `fread()` to read the entire file into the buffer
6. use `memcmp()` to compare the file contents to the string you already have

As an alternative you could use `glob()` instead of `readdir()` and manually matching against ".png" with `strstr`.

Comment: You missed the point of 3 and 4. You don't need to malloc a buffer to hold `struct stat` -- just declare it the object (not a pointer) on the stack and pass a pointer to the object to `stat()`. Also you need to check the return value from `stat()` -- it is returning an error which is why you're getting a negative value for the size. You need to pass the path to the file, which includes the directory. You can construct a path string by using `snprintf()` with a stack buffer and passing in the dir name and the file name.